# MissingApiVersionParameter when querying Azure Application Insights API with Python SDK and CLI client credentials

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-sdk-python

When I try to query **Application Insights** with **Python SDK** - using **Azure CLI client credentials**

```
client = get_client_from_cli_profile(ApplicationInsightsDataClient)

appInsightsQuery = QueryBody(query="""requests
        | where timestamp >= ago(1d)
        | summarize count() by user_AuthenticatedId""")

print(client.query.execute(appInsightsAppId,appInsightsQuery).tables[0])
```

I get this error

```
(MissingApiVersionParameter) The api-version query parameter (?api-version=) is required for all requests.
```

Answer (score 0):

Transforming from this Log Analytics issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/4544 - for the current version of `azure-applicationinsights 0.1.0` - the creation of `ApplicationInsightsDataClient` needs to be modified:

```
creds, _ = get_azure_cli_credentials(resource="https://api.applicationinsights.io")
client = ApplicationInsightsDataClient(creds)

appInsightsQuery = QueryBody(query="""requests
        | where timestamp >= ago(1d)
        | summarize count() by user_AuthenticatedId""")

print(client.query.execute(appInsightsAppId,appInsightsQuery).tables[0])
```

Comment: related issue in Application Insights Python SDK: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/14287

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in azure-common 1.1.26
https://pypi.org/project/azure-common/1.1.26/

Re-install a fresh virtual environment, or update azure-common and you should be fine :)

(I work at MS in the Python SDK team)